# Unable to connect to Hbase remotly

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I have set up Hadoop and Hbase in pseudo distributed mode on machine A.
I am running my client ( Java program ) from machine B.(Machine A and B can communicate with each other).
But i am facing problem in doing so.

My client code looks like this :

Configuration config = HBaseConfiguration.create();
config.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum" ,zookeeperLocation);    config.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort","2181");
HtablePool tablePool = new HTablePool(config,Integer.MAX_VALUE);
HTableInterface table = tablePool.getTable(tableName);

My code gets hang on last line( tablePool.getTable() ) and does not proceed.
In ZooKeeper logs , i see that request was received to connect but some how it did not proceed ahead.
I am really confused.
Please help here.

Answer (score 2):

I got solution to this problem , 
I tried different things like 
1) replacing hostname with ip addresses in all configuration files
2) playing with /etc/hosts file
3) stopping and starting both hadoop and hbase.